# why it couldn't catch exception in c++?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

my precious friends;

why c++ can't catch an exception in this example? could you please explain us? i tried it a lot but still couldn't. if i input a char in cmd, the catch block doesn't work.

```
try {
    int dX = 0;
    cin >> dX;
    dX = static_cast<double>(10 / dX);
    cout << dX << endl;
}
catch (conts std::exception &exp) { // if I input any of chars, it doesn't catch?
    cerr << "Error: " << exp->what() << endl;
}
```

Comment: `std::istream` doesn't throw exceptions on invalid input, unless you explicitly tell it to do so.

Comment: One also does not catch a pointer to an exception, but a reference.

Comment: Just to add a reference with rationale to @BaummitAugen's (correct) statement- [here](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/network/2003/05/05/cpluspocketref.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing does not throw an exception thus you are able to catch anything. An error (and maybe a lower level exception is thrown) but it is nothing that you can manage with a handler.

Other days catch your exceptions like this:

```
try
{
}
catch (const std::exception& error)
{
// handler
}
```

Comment: i couldn’t understand :/
when i write an example on c# such like below; c# always throw an exception.

so what can i do which above example so as to work on c++? how can i catch a global exception that is work always and every code?

c# example:

try 
{
 string abc = “char test”;
 Conversion.ToInt(abc);
}
catch(Exception exp)
{
 MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
}

Answer (score 0):

None of you code would throw an exception.
That is why it is not being caught (because there is not one).

Normally you want to check the state of the read operation to make sure it worked explicitly.

```
int dX = 0;
if (cin >> dX) {
    // Read worked.
    dX = static_cast<double>(10 / dX);
    cout << dX << endl;
}
else {
    // Read failed.
    cerr << "Error: Read of number failed\n";
}
```

---

The above is the normal way to handle this.
But you can make the stream throw an exception.

```
// cin will throw on a read failure.
cin.exception(std::ios::fail);
try {
    int dX = 0;
    cin >> dX;                        // now this will throw if the input is not numeric.
    dX = static_cast<double>(10 / dX);
    cout << dX << "\n";
}
catch (std::exception const& exp) {
    cerr << "Error: " << exp.what() << "\n";
}
```